# MS-Teams media-Permission

Tags: android, node.js, microsoft-teams, manifest.json

I am trying to give access to my MS-Teams app to allow permission for microphone.
Its working fine in the task module on desktop where the /shield / shaped button is available but in android view the button is not visible to give access to microphone.

In the *manifest.json* I added `devicePermissions": [ "media", "notifications" ]`

[Desktop View]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG28N.png

[Mobile View where the shield icon is not visible]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwcYD.png

And Code snippets from the teams documentation is confusing a little bit.

````
 microsoftTeams.media.selectMedia({ maxMediaCount: 1, mediaType: microsoftTeams.media.MediaType.Audio }, (error: microsoftTeams.SdkError, attachments: microsoftTeams.media.Media[]) => {
     // If there's any error, an alert shows the error message/code
     if (error) {
         if (error.message) {
             alert(" ErrorCode: " + error.errorCode + error.message);
         } else {
             alert(" ErrorCode: " + error.errorCode);
         }
     }

     if (attachments) {
         // taking the first attachment  
         let audioResult = attachments[0];

         // setting audio string which can be used in Video tag
         let audioData = "data:" + audioResult.mimeType + ";base64," + audioResult.preview
     }
 });
 }```


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/native-device-permissions?tabs=desktop
````

Comment: Could you please provide the sample repo which you are following, so that we can try to repro the issue?

Comment: We followed this sample(https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-device-permissions/nodejs) and observed that in Teams desktop you will get /shield/ shaped button to enable or disable media/microphone and in Android(Mobile devices) you will get a pop up asking to allow access when you will click on Capture audio.

Comment: As mentioned  in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/mobile-camera-image-permissions):You can get Request Permissions prompt automatically displayed when a relevant Teams API is initiated.